# I cant install kivy through pip

Tags: python, pip, kivy

Im getting this error when installing kivy through pip, any help on this issue?

[image]

I would provide more info on the error if I could, but I don't even know what the error is called or why I am getting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the respective wheel file for your architecture, os and Python version from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Kivy and install the downloaded wheel through pip, as documented in https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#what-are-wheels-pip-and-wheel

excerpt from that Kivy docs,

> In Python, packages such as Kivy can be installed with the python
> package manager, pip. Some packages such as Kivy require additional
> steps, such as compilation, when installing using the Kivy source code
> with pip. Wheels (with a .whl extension) are pre-built distributions
> of a package that has already been compiled and do not require
> additional steps to install.
>
> When hosted on pypi one installs a wheel using pip, e.g. python -m pip
> install kivy. When downloading and installing a wheel directly, python
> -m pip install wheel_file_name is used, such as:
>
> python -m pip install C:\Kivy-1.9.1.dev-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl

Comment: Whilst this wasn't the solution to my particular problem it did highlight that I had installed a later version of Python (3.8) and this was not compatible with Kivy.  Once I dropped back to Python 3.7, Kivy installed successfully through pip.